# Can Flash and Javascript communicate?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am working on a chatting app that makes use of flash sockets. I don't want to code the entire interface in flash, so I was hoping to just use flash to talk to the socketserver and call js to modify the dom.

can this be done?

Comment: You may be interested in HTML5 websockets. They perform a similar function to Flash sockets. Downside is going to be browser support but it depends on your objectives and timeframe.

Comment: Hi Spliff, I originally implemented it using sockets and works great. Was disappointed by the browser support though (only Chrome currently) :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To call a JavaScript function from Flash, use the `ExternalInterface.call` function in ActionScript:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

// Call a JavaScript function
ExternalInterface.call("your_javascript_function");

// Get a return value from a JavaScript function
var x:int = ExternalInterface.call("get_x");

// Pass an argument to a JavaScript function
var retval:int = ExternalInterface.call("some_js_function", "the-argument");
```

To call an ActionScript function from JavaScript, first use the `ExternalInterface.addCallback` function in ActionScript:

```
// "methodName" is the method to call in JavaScript
// instanceObject.realMethod is the method that will be triggered
var successful = ExternalInterface.addCallback("methodName",
                                               instanceObject,
                                               realMethod);
```

Then, get a handle on the SWFObject in JavaScript and call the ActionScript method as follows:

```
function makeActionScriptCall() {
    var flash = document.getElementById(movieName);
    flash.methodName(parametersIfAny);
}
```

For more information, see:

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html
- http://codingrecipes.com/calling-a-javascript-function-from-actionscript-3-flash
- http://bytes.com/topic/flash/answers/694359-how-do-i-access-flash-function-using-javascript

Comment: ExternalInterface.call("your_javascript_function"); is already enough to call the function, you don't need to add the () inside the string.

Comment: Very thorough answer. Thank you. Is there anything to watch out for when doing this?

Comment: I just want to point out that the downvote is me and it's a misclick. I didn't realize I did it till just now... 15hrs later. Sorry. \*\*doh\*\*

Comment: No prob -- I appreciate the comment, otherwise I might have been scratching my head. :)

Answer (score 5):

Use the [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) object to have your ActionScript be able to call JavaScript functions and vice-versa.